# formatting multivalue lookup value using powershell - SharePoint 2013

Tags: powershell

What would be the best way to format this

```
   Brand Management;#2120;#Infinite Retail
```

I would like to strip the `;#2120;#` of and replace with `,`

Sometimes values are single

Thanks in advance

Comment: Powershell has a replace operator. $Lookup.Replace(";#2120;#",",")

Answer (score 2):

You could try the following regular expression `;#\d*;#` for multi-lookup value.

**PowerShell example**

```
$value = "Brand Management;#2120;#Infinite Retail"
$formattedValue = $value -replace ";#\d*;#", ","
```

Output: `Brand Management,Infinite Retail`

Comment: Good regex, you could maybe delete everything between ';' even if its not number (because if I remember well, '\d' means decimal). I don't know what the ops really wants

Comment: Thanks, regarding "if no number is specified" - this is exactly \d* is intended for ;)